# Generic Function: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, generics, decodable

I have a static function in a class that takes a generic type that must conform to decodable, however when I call this function I get the following error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". The Tour class (which is the type I'm passing to the function) conforms to Decodable and inherits from the CoreDataModel class.

This is occurring on the new Xcode 12.0 Beta in DashboardNetworkAdapter when I call CoreDataModel.create (line 7 on the snippet I've shared for that class).

Edit minimal reproducible example:

**DashboardNetworkAdapter:**

```
class DashboardNetworkAdapter {
    
    // MARK: - GET
    
    public func syncTours(page: Int, completion: @escaping(Bool, Error, Bool) -> Void) {
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Tours", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                CoreDataModel.create(Array<Tour>.self, from: data) { success, error in
                    completion(success, error, false)
                }
            } catch let error {
                completion(false, error, false)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**CoreDataModel:**

```
public class CoreDataModel: NSManagedObject {
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    
    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var updatedAt: Date?


    
    // MARK: - CRUD
    
    static func create<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) where T : Decodable {
        DataCoordinator.performBackgroundTask { context in
            do {
                let _ = try DataDecoder(context: context).decode(type, from: data, completion: {
                    completion(true, nil)
                })
            } catch let error {
                completion(false, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tour:**

```
@objc(Tour)
class Tour: CoreDataModel, Decodable {
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var image: URL?
    @NSManaged public var owned: Bool
    @NSManaged public var price: Double
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Coding Keys
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case image = "image"
        case owned = "owned"
        case price = "price"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Initializer
    
    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Cannot find decoding context")}
        self.init(context: context)
        
        let topLevel = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PaginatedResponseCodingKeys.self)
        let values = try topLevel.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)
        let id = try values.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .id)
        let name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let image = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .image)
        let owned = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .owned)
        let price = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .price)
        let updatedAt = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .updatedAt)
        let createdAt = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .createdAt)
        
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = URL(string: image)
        self.owned = owned == 1
        self.price = price
        self.updatedAt = updatedAt
        self.createdAt = createdAt
    }
    
    
    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tour", in: context) else { fatalError() }
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }
    
}
```

**DataDecoder:**

```
class DataDecoder: JSONDecoder {
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
    private var persistent: Bool = true
    
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    
    public init(persistent: Bool = true, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        super.init()
        
        self.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ (decoder) -> Date in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let string = try container.decode(String.self)

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            locale = .autoupdatingCurrent
            dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

            return dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
        })
        
        self.context = context
        userInfo[.context] = context
    }
    
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Utilities
    
        public func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
            let result = try super.decode(type, from: data)
            
            if(persistent) {
                saveContext(completion: completion)
            }
            return result
        }
        
        
        private func saveContext(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)  {
            guard let context = context else { fatalError("Cannot Find Decoding Context") }
            context.performAndWait {
                try? context.save()
                completion?()
                context.reset()
            }
        }
        
    }
```

**CodingUserInfoKey Extension:**

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
    
}
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?  What is `Tour`, `data` and `completion`? Can you show their declarations?

Comment: Maybe not relevant to the issue but `Tour` is not the type you are passing to the function, it is `[Tour]` that is the type.

Comment: If `Tour` is `Decodable`, passing `[Tour].self` to the method should still work

Comment: @Sweeper updated to include the relevant info, data is literally just the encoded json data coming from an api response and completion is just a completion block...

Comment: @JamesWolfe, where's the error happening and where are you calling what function? I can sort of get it from the pre-edited original question, but can you update this edit to be clearer of where the error is happening

Comment: @NewDev I've done that for you now and included a snippet of the class that's calling it.

Comment: @JamesWolfe - One issue I immediately see is that the outer completion function expects a non-optional `Error`, whereas the `create`'s method completion expects an optional `Error?`.

Comment: @NewDev wow. Put this as an answer so I can mark it as correct and forget this entire embarrassing scenario ever happened!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a type mismatch between what `completion` closure expects for its `Error` parameter, and what it gets from the inferred type of the `CoreDataModel.create` completion closure, which is `Error?`:

```
public func syncTours(page: Int, completion: @escaping(Bool, Error, Bool) -> Void) {
   ...

        CoreDataModel.create(Array<Tour>.self, from: data) { success, error in
            // error is of type Error?, but completion expects Error
            completion(success, error, false)
        }
   ...
}
```

In general, whenever you face type inference issues or errors, make each type explicit, and you'll see exactly exactly where the mismatch is. For example, below you could be explicit about the inner closure signature:

```
CoreDataModel.create([Tour].self, from: data) { (success: Bool, err: Error?) -> Void in

}
```